# How to perform subtraction of 1st and last repetition number in python?

Tags: python

I am having following string in file

```
1 , d = 01
2 , d = 01
3 , d = 01
4 , d = 01
5 , d = 01
6 , d = 02
7 , d = 02
8 , d = 02
9 , d = 03
10 , d = 03
11 , d = 03
```

I want to perform subtraction operation of 1st and last repetition number ,

For example :

for d= 01 i need to perform 5-1

for d =02 i need to perform 8-6

Can you please help me or give some hint.

Comment: Where is the connection between the regex in your code and your example data? There is no `val` , `IR` or `[BUFFER1` part.

Comment: you can say example data is output of regex perform , initially there is bunch of unwanted data that i removed by using this regex, not able to think that example logic now.

Comment: Why do you show this code in this question where it is not relevant? Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including what you have tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: not able to try also , i need to some hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses a simple regex to extract the numbers and `itertools.groupby` to assemble the groups where `d` is the same:

```
from itertools import groupby
from re import match

with open('capture.log') as f:
    lines = [tuple(
        map(int, match(r"(\d+) , d = (\d+)", line).group(1, 2))
    ) for line in f]

for group in groupby(lines, lambda line: line[1]):
    n = [t[0] for t in group[1]]
    print(f"{n[-1]} - {n[0]} = {n[-1] - n[0]}")
```

```
5 - 1 = 4
8 - 6 = 2
11 - 9 = 2
```